# Shortening PHP regex

Tags: php, regex

When writing applications I always come to a point where I have to use regexes. And I think regexes are very hard so I use text2re when creating them. I think they create such long code and there must be better ways if done manually.

I need to match IMEI numbers which are 15 digits and text2re says this is they way to do it:

```
//TRIM IMEI
  function fixIMEI($txt)
{
    $re1='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re2='\\d';   # Uninteresting: d
  $re3='.*?';   # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re4='\\d';   # Uninteresting: d
  $re5='.*?';   # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re6='\\d';   # Uninteresting: d
  $re7='.*?';   # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re8='\\d';   # Uninteresting: d
  $re9='.*?';   # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re10='\\d';  # Uninteresting: d
  $re11='.*?';  # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re12='\\d';  # Uninteresting: d
  $re13='.*?';  # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re14='\\d';  # Uninteresting: d
  $re15='.*?';  # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re16='\\d';  # Uninteresting: d
  $re17='.*?';  # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re18='(\\d)';    # Any Single Digit 1
  $re19='(\\d)';    # Any Single Digit 2
  $re20='(\\d)';    # Any Single Digit 3
  $re21='(\\d)';    # Any Single Digit 4
  $re22='(\\d)';    # Any Single Digit 5
  $re23='(\\d)';    # Any Single Digit 6
  $re24='(\\d)';    # Any Single Digit 7
  $re25='(\\d)';    # Any Single Digit 8
  $re26='(\\d)';    # Any Single Digit 9
  $re27='(\\d)';    # Any Single Digit 10
  $re28='(\\d)';    # Any Single Digit 11
  $re29='(\\d)';    # Any Single Digit 12
  $re30='(\\d)';    # Any Single Digit 13
  $re31='(\\d)';    # Any Single Digit 14
  $re32='(\\d)';    # Any Single Digit 15

  if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2.$re3.$re4.$re5.$re6.$re7.$re8.$re9.$re10.$re11.$re12.$re13.$re14.
                         $re15.$re16.$re17.$re18.$re19.$re20.$re21.$re22.$re23.$re24.$re25.$re26.$re27.
                         $re28.$re29.$re30.$re31.$re32."/is", $txt, $matches))
  {
      $d1=$matches[1][0];
      $d2=$matches[2][0];
      $d3=$matches[3][0];
      $d4=$matches[4][0];
      $d5=$matches[5][0];
      $d6=$matches[6][0];
      $d7=$matches[7][0];
      $d8=$matches[8][0];
      $d9=$matches[9][0];
      $d10=$matches[10][0];
      $d11=$matches[11][0];
      $d12=$matches[12][0];
      $d13=$matches[13][0];
      $d14=$matches[14][0];
      $d15=$matches[15][0];
      return "$d1$d2$d3$d4$d5$d6$d7$d8$d9$d10$d11$d12$d13$d14$d15";
  }

}
```

Comment: What is text2re and what did you ask them to write an regex for?

Comment: txt2re.com is the site

Comment: If you're using [this tool](http://txt2re.com/) then it can most certainly generate a shorter regex than that. Try clicking "int" instead of "d", for instance.

Comment: You can't match an IMEI ( other than \d{15} ), to check for at least correctness you have to compute the checkdigit (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMEI#Check_digit_computation)

Answer (score 1):

I think this regular expression should work according to [Wikipedia IMEI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Station_Equipment_Identity):

```
/\b\d{2}-?\d{6}-?\d{6}-?(?:\d{1,2})?\b/isg
```

assuming that `-` characters may be omitted.

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rI0zD3/1)**

Of course this one only get numbers, but in case you want also make sure this is valid IMEI, you should calculate checksum using algorithm on previous mentioned Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

This function would do the same as the one you posted:

```
function fixIMEI($txt) {
  if (preg_match ("/(.*?\\d){8}.*?(\\d{15})/is", $txt, $match))
     return $match[2];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want so get 15 digits from a string, i would recommend this regex expression:

```
[\d]{15}
```

Comment: It is not just 15 digits. There is something more complicated to it.